# Alfresco Process Services involved task notifications

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I am working on the Alfresco Process Services and came across the below requirements.

1. I want to send an email when I involve someone in the task. The involved person should get an email notification. Right now, by default the email notification is not going to the involved person.
2. Also, is there any way to make the attached documents and task form read only except the task claimer? I mean, only the task claimer should be able to edit the task but all other users in the group should be able to view the task in read only mode.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: 1. Is it custom workflow or existing? 2.Once user claim a task then other user are not able view so how you want to show as read only?

Comment: it is a custom workflow. The group user wants to see task details even though it is claimed by one of the group members.

Comment: By Default , alfresco is not providing that functionality.